# How to delete row in SAPUI5 table with delete button embedded in the row

Tags: json, sapui5

I have XML SAPUI5 table with delete button embedded in each rows. Table is bound to a JSON..

```
<Table id="idUploadTable" mode="None" delete="handleDeleteListItem" width="100%" 
items="{uiFormModel>/attachmentList}">

    <columns>
        <Column id="idFileNameCol" vAlign="Middle">
            <header>
                <Label text="File Name" />
            </header>
        </Column>
        <Column id="idUploadedOByCol" hAlign="Left" vAlign="Middle">
            <header>
                <Label text="Uploaded By" />
            </header>
        </Column>
        <Column id="idUploadedOnCol" hAlign="Left" vAlign="Middle">
            <header>
                <Label text="Uploaded On" />
            </header>
        </Column>
        <Column id="idUploadedDelCol" hAlign="Left" vAlign="Middle">
            <header>
                <Label text="" />
            </header>
        </Column>                           
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Link text="{uiFormModel>fileName}" href="{uiFormModel>fileLocation}" target="blank"/>
                <Text text="{uiFormModel>uploadedByUserName}" />
                <Text text="{uiFormModel>uploadedOn}" />
                <Button icon="sap-icon://delete" press="handleDeleteAttachment">
                    <customData>
                        <core:CustomData key="multi" value="true" />
                    </customData>
                </Button>                                   
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Table is bound to a JSON model
I am able to load data from the above JSON to the table. **What I want is, when user clicks on delete button embedded in the row, that specific row needs to be deleted**. `Table selection mode has to be None`. How can I achieve this with the above mentioned code as the baseline?

Thanks in advance..
Faddy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Remove Row from Table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48521618/5846045)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the handler for the button click, you need to get the "binding path". This is a path in the model from the root to the instance data. With that you can get it's value, then go to your model, select the corresponding instance and remove it. The table updates automatically. The binding path part is something along the lines of :

```
new sap.ui.commons.Button({ /* ... */
  press: function(e){
    var sPath = e.getSource().getBindingContext('uiFormModel').getPath();
    var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel('uiFormModel');
    var oRowData = oModel.getProperty(sPath);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: and the deletion with Javascript splice-method (splicing the index of the row .splice(i,1) and then rebind the json model to you table)